# Use ProxyCommand for all SSH Connections

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openssh

I was playing around with the idea of having a SSH Proxy Server or otherwise called Jump Host, which I would use to connect to all of my *"hidden"* Servers. So basically I have the following setup. Please note I intentionally use IP addresses here instead of hostname.

```
<client> ---> <proxy_ssh> ---> <192.168.0.*>
```

My intention is that it should be as transparent for the users as possible. So ideally the users should only have to execute the following command

```
# ssh user@192.168.0.10
```

To get this working I've created the following `.ssh/config`.

```
Host *                                                                                                                                                                           
    ServerAliveInterval 240                                                                                                                                                      
    Compression yes                                                                                                                                                              
    ForwardAgent yes                                                                                                                                                             
    ForwardX11 yes                                                                                                                                                               

Host 192.168.0.*                                                                                                                                                                   
    ProxyCommand ssh my_user@proxy_ssh.example.com netcat -w 120 %h %p
```

This works fine. But it is kind of tedious if I would have more networks to work with behind my `proxy_ssh` server. So I've tried simply adding the `ProxyCommand` to the `Host *` section which did not work.

I've wanted to make this more transparent for the end user, and changed the ssh config to the following, simply leaving out the specific Host definition.

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 240                                                                                                                                                      
    Compression yes                                                                                                                                                              
    ForwardAgent yes                                                                                                                                                             
    ForwardX11 yes                                                                                                                                                               
    ProxyCommand ssh my_user@proxy_ssh.example.com netcat -w 120 %h %p
```

This had the impact that I was not able to connect any longer to the endhost. The connection simply timed out!

So hence my question is there any way of having this more transparent in such a way that all of my SSH connection would use the `proxy_ssh` host?

Comment: *which did not work.* ... what errors you get? How the configuration looked like?

Comment: Added the example I've actually tried

Comment: The example above will make it recursive, that every connection will use a proxy command, which is ssh with just another proxy commmand. Good way to DOS your proxy. You should exclude the proxy from the list or use `-F /dev/null` to ignore the configuration for the proxy command.

Comment: By specifying `-F /dev/null` I will overwrite the config all together If I understand the man page correctly. That's not what I want.

Comment: Only in the `ProxyCommand` ssh. The other possibility is to overwrite only the `ProxyCommand` using `-oProxyCommand=none`.

Comment: Ok Perfect that works like a charm. So I've edited the line ProxyCommand `.ssh/config` to the following `ProxyCommand ssh -oProxyCommand=none my_user@proxy_ssh.example.com netcat -w 120 %h %p` . So in fact you can post exactly that as answer :)

Comment: More importantly, if you have these sort of wildcard configurations, have them appear later in your `.config`, after the more specific entries. According to https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5 the *first* encountered value for a specific value is the one used, so a later "override" will be ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example above will make it recursive, that every connection will use a proxy command, which is again ssh with another proxy command. Good way to DOS your proxy.

You should exclude the proxy from the list, use `-F /dev/null` to ignore the configuration for the proxy command or just ignore the proxy command for the proxy ssh:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -oProxyCommand=none my_user@proxy_ssh.example.com netcat -w 120 %h %p
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an entry to the config for the jump host that overrides the proxy command:

```
Host proxy_ssh.example.com
  ProxyCommand none
```

Otherwise it will try to use the proxy command to get to the jump host itself.